# Побитовые операции PHP

Tags: php

`$steamID = 76561198021498838;
$temp = 4294967295;
$steamID = $steamID & $temp;`

Если считать это на калькуляторе то получается 61233110, если же этот код обрабатывается на сервере, то возвращает 61233104, то есть ошибается на 1 и 2 бит.
Подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Переполнение целых чисел**
> Если PHP обнаружил, что число превышает размер типа integer, он будет интерпретировать его в качестве float. Аналогично, если результат операции лежит за границами типа integer, он будет преобразован в float.

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.integer.php
и попробуйте такой код:

```
$x=4294967295; // это срез Вашего числа, чтобы не было переполнения
$y=4356200406;
echo $x & $y;
```

Чтобы понять что действительно произошло переполнение сделайте

```
echo $steamID; // 7.6561198021499E+16
```

Как решить эту задачу:

```
$x=gmp_init("76561198021498838");
$y=gmp_init("4294967295");
echo gmp_strval(gmp_and($x, $y)); // 61233110
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за совет. Поскольку библиотека gmp не подключена на моем сервере я решил пусть так и будет, а проблему решил с помощью уже подключенной BC Math, и сделал все побитовые операции вручную.